# How to run PHP as backend and Angular as frontend

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angular, api

I have a project and using angular as front end and PHP as back end, installed both in different domains, PHP project is complete and working. I have created API in PHP and in angular I will call that API.

can I do like copy PHP project into angular src folder and run or using different domains how can I call API Or how?

what is the most used way for doing this I have seen tutorials over this but not able to get it correctly?

so can you please tell me any way to work,please give me your suggestion and thoughts

Comment: Try this: https://therichpost.com/angular-8-with-mysql-database-working-example/

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a big question really.

No-one will be able to give you an answer as to how to do what you're trying to achieve in a single stackoverflow post. It's like asking "how do I build a car?" - there are many steps involved to complete this process. Your best bet is to follow a tutorial.

In my experience, having separate applications for front end and backend is quite common.

You should keep your PHP project separate to your Angular project instead of mixing them.

You should follow a tutorial on how to build a full stack application such as these:

- https://morioh.com/p/f2ad5d91a8dd
- https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/develop-angular-php-app-getting-the-list-of-items
- https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-php-mysql-database/

Good luck!